Combining two bijective maps over the union of two domains to create a bijection
Let $A,A^{'}$ and $B,B^{'}$ be finite sets. Assume there exists bijective (one-to-one and onto) maps $f_1:A\rightarrow A^{'}$ and $f_2:B\rightarrow B^{'}$. Also assume there exists bijective maps $g_1:A\rightarrow B$ and $g_2:A^{'}\rightarrow B^{'}$.
Is it possible to create a bijection $h:A\cup B \rightarrow A^{'}\cup B^{'}$, by making use of $f_1$ and $f_2$ (and if required, using $g_1$ and $g_2$).
We can assume $|A\cap B| = |A^{'}\cap B^{'}|$.
Is it possible to create a bijection $h_1:A\cap B\rightarrow A^{'} \cap B^{'}$.

Minor point: you’re using the symbil $\mapsto$ wrong. It’s what we use to express that a single element of a function’s range goes to a particular element of its range. You want a simple $\rightarrow$, which MathJax will make from \rightarrow.

I meant to use \mapsto. I will make the change.

See this question for an explanation of how $\rightarrow$ and $\mapsto$ are used.

What do you mean “we can assume $|A \cap B|=|A^\prime \cap B^\prime | $”?  In general this is not the case.

Yes, in general it is not true. In the specific case I am considering, I am allowed to use this extra information.

Of course we can create a bijection $h:A\cap B\to A'\cap B'$ if $|A\cap B|=|A'\cap B'|$; however, you want to create $h$ "using" $f_1$, $f_2$, $g_1$, and $g_2$. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "using", but perhaps the following is a counterexample.
Let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, $C=\{4,5\}$, $D=\{5,6\}$.
Define a bijection $f_1:A\to A'$, $f_1(1)=5$, $f_1(2)=4$.
Define a bijection $f_2:B\to B'$, $f_2(2)=6$, $f_2(3)=5$.
Define a bijection $g_1:A\to B$, $g_1(1)=3$, $g_1(2)=2$.
Define a bijection $g_2:A'\to B'$, $g_2(4)=6$, $g_2(5)=5$.
The bijection $h:A\cap B\to A'\cap B'$ is $h(2)=5$; can you get that using $f_1$, $f_2$, $g_1$, and $g_2$?

Thanks for the explanation. Indeed a bijection will exist. But, the construction of $h$ needs to use $f_1$ and $f_2$, and if required $g_1$ and $g_2$.

How is it supposed to "use" the given functions? In the example I gave, how can the bijection $h(2)=5$ "use" the given functions, seeing as those functions map ${1,3,5}\to{1,3,5}$ and ${2,4,6}\to{2,4,6}$? Apparently your undefined term "use" must mean something beyond composing and inverting functions but I can't imagine what.
